# Tabs within an expandable/nested table

Tags: tables, tabs

Has anyone tried a solution where you have a nested table where you expand a row and get a set of tabs within the area? If so, how did the user experience it? Was it obvious what happened and how the information was correlated or did it cause any problems?

Note: It's a table in a web application. The design of the table are quite airy and "modern", not an old-fashioned excel design

[image][image]

Comment: This is a very complicated interface, actually the tab representation usually be in the very top the data set. -- why don't you start your interface by the tabs and nest in it the data you what.

Comment: It is indeed a very complicated interface since it is a very complicated system. I can't start with the tabs since each row in the table will have a different setup of tabs. And this isn't the beginning of a drill down, the image I'm showing is already a few levels down in a page hierarchy

Comment: I would rather to simplify the interface by redirect the user to a page that have all the tabs you like with a back button rather that using a collapseable panel.

Comment: Have you looked at the accessibility issues involved in structuring something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea.  Another option might be to group the data when you click the table row and display it directly. The reason I suggest this is once a user clicked something, I guess it is the plus (+) in your diagram, do they want to click further to drill down to the application?
[image]
This all depends on the amount of data you need to show of course.

Or another option might be a consatina/accordion set of groups but that re-introduces the second click.